# Q: Unable to activate Evernote API key (Activate page does not respond)

Tags: evernote

I'm trying to activate my API key with Evernote using the below link:

https://dev.evernote.com/support/

When I complete the form and click the submit button, the page does not give any respond. How can I do to solve this problem to activate evernote api key?

[The activation request page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhKqU.png)

Answer (score 0):

After submit, scroll up the screen and you should see a popup window.